# Translating a Linq query from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

What would be the code equivalent of this to c#?

*VB code*

```
Dim q = From p In commDS.Tables(1).AsEnumerable() _
                    Join e In ds.Tables(1).AsEnumerable() On p.Field(Of Integer)("JobID") Equals e.Field(Of Integer)("JobID") And _
                    p.Field(Of Integer)("EventID") Equals e.Field(Of Integer)("EventID") _
                    Select New With {Key .resRow = p, Key .eRow = e}
```

Below is what I'm trying but it's quite wrong.

```
 var q = (from p in commDs.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                     join e in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() on 
                     p.Field<int>("JobID") equals e.Field<int>("JobID")
                     && e.Field<int>("EventID") equals p.Field<int>("EventID")
        Select new{ p,e}
        );
```

Comment: You could try this tool: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: tried it, but the converter return EOF error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize VB would let you join on multiple values like that.  In C# the equivalent would be to create an anonymous type for the join key(s):

```
 var q = (from p in commDs.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                     join e in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                     on new {JobID = p.Field<int>("JobID"), EventID = p.Field<int>("EventID") }
                       equals new {JobID = e.Field<int>("JobID"), EventID = e.Field<int>("EventID") }
        select new {p,e}
        );
```

The only other difference is that the resulting anonymous type has different field names (`p` and `e` versus `resRow`, `eRow`), but that's easy enough to change.

Comment: I'm a bit confuse, tried your code but compiler saying The name 'e' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.

Comment: @user2058252 Try it again; I had two references to `p` and `e` flipped (specifically on the join clause)

Comment: Cool seems fine now, quite amaze now I understand my mistake a while ago.

Comment: You probably want to have the anonymous type stay the same - select new {resRow = p, eRow = e}.